# jQuery Cycle plugin pagerAnchorBuilder images becoming undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cycle, undefined

I have a slideshow built in flash that I want to mimic in jQuery. The slide show uses the images from the slideshow as the pager numbers. The problem im having is once i apply links to the slideshow images the pagerAnchorBuilder image returns an undefined for the src of the image.

Javascript -

```
$(function() {
$('#slideshow').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    timeout: 7000,
    pager:  '#nav',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>';
    }
});  
});
```

HTML -

```
<div id="slideshow" class="pics"> 
    <a href="http://google.com"><img src="home_1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" /></a>
    <a href="http://google.com"><img src="home_2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" /></a>
    <a href="http://google.com"><img src="home_3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" /></a> 
    <a href="http://google.com"><img src="home_4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" /></a> 
    <a href="http://google.com"><img src="home_5.jpg" width="1000" height="600" /></a> 

</div>
```

If i remove the href's from the slideshow the images in the pager show up without issues. Im not sure if this is a bug or something i need to find a fix for?

Here is the answer -

```
$(function() {
$('#slideshow').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    timeout: 7000,
    pager:  '#nav',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
      var img = $(slide).children().eq(0).attr("src");
      return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + img + '" width="100" height="60" /></a></li>';
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this may help you!

> [jQuery Cycle pagerAnchorBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370127/jquery-cycle-pageranchorbuilder)

Answer (score 3):

I used `JQuery.find()` to help find the images, and to keep the code modular enough to use with different markup:

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="'
        + jQuery(slide).find('img').attr('src')
        + '" width="120" /></a></li>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With reference to JVerstry's comment (nice one JV btw!), I got the following going just fine which uses the image and `<a>`link. Also the pager thumbs also show the main image alt attribute:

```
return '<li class="slider-thumb"><a href="'+slide.href+'" id="pager-click" title="'+slide.title+'"><img src="'+ $(slide).find('img').attr('src')+'" width="90" height="69" class="fader" /></a><p class="slide-caption">'+ $(slide).find('img').attr('alt')+'</p></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a common problem! Check out [cycle with anchors](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/anchor.html) and also cycle's "slideExpr"